# issue with css and firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm updating my website and I'm having problems with my css, I added an image to the footer to let the user change the language, to do this I added some style at the beginning of the css file and used the style made on my html.

When I was working on the update I was testing all the changes using firefox, the code/update was working fine when I tested the changes from my hard disk.

I had updated my website on my server and now the website only works on chrome, the css style doesn't work when I try to load my website on firefox or Microsoft edge, only works fine on google chrome.

Here is the code I had added to the css file at the beginning of the file to avoid nesting problems with the others styles.

```css
#language {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div id="language">
  <a href="index_spa.html" title="Spanish" target="_parent"><img src="images/quantic/social/spanish_flag.png" alt="Spanish" class="img-responsive" /></a>
</div>
```

As I said at the beginning of the post, it works on google chrome (from my HD and online) on firefox works only from my HD.

I'm not an html/css guru, please I need some help to fix this issue, sorry if this is kinda newbie question.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: What actually do you mean by `not working`? Does not load an image? or wrong position?
For the image try to use absolute path which you can open in the browser.

Comment: I put your code in [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/91yu2e5x/1), but there is no difference between the browsers. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Have you made sure you updated all links respectively to the new domain or path of the server you've uploaded it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution using the firefox developers tools, when i used it i found 4 errors issues in the google analytics javascript, i had removed the google javascript code and the website has returned to work just fine.